# Roots of Unity and Expressing numbers as linear combinations of primes

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

I am currently in high school and we just finished learning about complex numbers.
 While looking at a problem called the Centrifuge problem: 
https://mattbaker.blog/2018/06/25/the-balanced-centrifuge-problem/. 
I came across 2 conjectures and I wanted to know how the roots of unity are related to linear combinations of prime numbers:

---

this is the conjecture:

- For any integers $n ≥ 2$ and $1 ≤ k ≤ n$, one may find k distinct $n^{\rm th}$ roots of unity whose sum is 0 if and only if both $k$ and $n − k$ are expressible as linear combinations of prime factors of $n$ with nonnegative coefficients.

  - can someone explain this relation?
  - is there a proof for this which can be understood using elementary knowledge of number theory and complex numbers.

Comment: Note: As Matt Baker's blog mentions, this is proven in [Gary Sivek, *On vanishing sums of distinct roots of unity*, Integers **10** (2010), pp. 365--368](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/k31/k31.pdf). The proof looks completely elementary to me (but I haven't checked). Lemma 5 is the famous Chicken McNugget theorem (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_number#n_.3D_2 ).